# Symfony 4 flex - make:entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

Is it possible to generate entities mapping in yaml file instead of annotations using `make:entity` command? I am not a big fan of annotations mapping. In Symfony 2 you could chose what type of mapping you want.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine 3 is [removing the YAML mapping drivers](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/85243a60b55c9e8042471c42d49871e59d438dd2/UPGRADE.md), so they would not be usable.

If you don't want to use annotations instead, you can still use the XML format.